# How to convert a type to Number in JavaScript from Sharepoint

Tags: development, javascript, visual-studio-2013

I have the following solution,

this is my SharePoint list [image: this is my SP list it is of type text]

and here is my UserInterface xhtml and form

[image: xhtml v1.1]
[image]

and here is the problem, when i retrieve this field "koha" using the follwoing code:
[image]

it always says NaN:NaN it seems that i missing a cast here is my other code
[image]

this #UItimer is this[image]

how can i show the value of ``koha` and display it as a Number?

anyone can help me?

Comment: First check what you get: ``console.log(typeof uitimer,uitimer)``

Comment: I have used the following comand `alert(duration);``alert(typeof duration);` and it says: unidentified, unidentified

Comment: So the problem is how you get the value, not your (later) JS. Learn the correct syntax: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=get_fieldvalues

Comment: yes any suggestion?

Comment: See the link in my previous comment, learn how to use ``get_fieldvalues()``